# JodaTime : Convert local to UTC ambiguity

Tags: java, date, timezone, jodatime, utc

I am trying to convert local date to UTC by using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). The code that I used is shown below and it works great.

```
Date localDate = new Date();
System.out.println("Local Date : " + localDate);

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
Date utcDate = new Date(tz.convertLocalToUTC(localDate.getTime(), false));
System.out.println("UTC Date : " + utcDate);

Output :  
Local Date : Wed May 29 11:54:46 EEST 2013
UTC Date : Wed May 29 08:54:46 EEST 2013
```

But, if I send UTC Date as a parameter to the [DateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#convertUTCToLocal%28long%29) method, it also decreases the hour by 3.
However, since it is UTC Date, I expect it not to convert date again. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
Date localDate = new Date();
System.out.println("Local Date : " + localDate);

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
Date utcDate = new Date(tz.convertLocalToUTC(localDate.getTime(), false));
System.out.println("UTC Date : " + utcDate);

Date utcDate2 = new Date(tz.convertLocalToUTC(utcDate.getTime(), false));
System.out.println("UTC Date 2 : " + utcDate2);

Output : 
Local Date : Wed May 29 11:54:46 EEST 2013
UTC Date : Wed May 29 08:54:46 EEST 2013
UTC Date 2 : Wed May 29 05:54:46 EEST 2013
```

Answer (score 6):

As per javadoc of `convertLocalToUTC`

> Converts a local instant to a standard UTC instant with the same local
>   time. This conversion is used after performing a calculation where the
>   calculation was done using a simple local zone.

Methods makes no assumption or validation that passed date is in `UTC` or not, it always consider passed date as local and converts to `UTC`. Your program output is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it from the `convertLocalToUTC()` methods point of view.  It just takes a `long` and a `boolean`.  It does not have any knowledge that the long you are passing it is `UTC` or not.  It assumes that you are passing a `long` that is local time and adjusts it accordingly.